# How to select best feature set and not ranking for tree based models?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-mining, predictive-modeling, feature-selection

I am currently using `feature selection` approaches like `filter, wrapper, embedded` etc.

All these methods give different set of features and I rank them based on their frequency of occurrence in other feature selection approach.

Ex: If `Age` occurs in all 6 feature selection algorithm, then they will have a rank as `6`. If `gender` occurs only in 2 feature selection algorithm, its rank would be 2.

So I arrange them in descending order and choose the features which has occurred in at least 3-4 feature selection algorithm.

But where I am trying to seek your help is

1) Is there any systematic way where I get only a subset of features which returns best output? I thought `genetic algorithm` for feature selection will return a feature subset which will give high output. But unfortunately it lists all features with their importance. I don't wish to define a threshold myself to select few. Example is currently Xgboost produces an F1-score of 81 with around 27-28 features but when I manually play around, it gives around 81.9 or 82.1 with just 6-7 features.  So I would like to have a way to select this 6-7 features automatically/systematically without human intervention

2) Is there any algorithm, like `RFE` but **which does exhaustive search** like genetic algorithm and finally returns us the best feature set? Mix of RFE and genetic algorithm is what I need

3) I wish to have an exhaustive search in feature space and finally provide me the best feature set which will provide best `f1-SCORE` which is my objective.

I am looking for a systematic way/algorithmic way to do this rather than me deciding to pick features which occurs at least in 3 feat selection algorithms

Hope my question is clear. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that what you are looking for is [Best Subset, Forward Stepwise, or Lasso?](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/papers/bestsubset.pdf)

Here is the R implementation [Best Subset](https://github.com/ryantibs/best-subset/)

If anyone knows a python implementation, please let me know!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. upvoted.Does Best subset applies to `Xgboost`?

Comment: I understand that yes, but It is extremely expensive (check page 11)